# Undefined index with $_POST when the index is actually defined

Tags: php, html

I've seen lots of questions asked about this symptom, but none of the answers seem to meet my problem. I'm getting notices like this (15 of them, one for each variable passed from the form) and the result is the page a user sees is blank.

> Notice: Undefined index: FirstName in C:\Web Files\www.iusc.org\scripts\send_form_email.php on line 3

Yet when I peek into the POST with Firebug in Firefox, I see the variables (all 15) properly populated.

Per requests I'll include all of both files. Here is the bulk of the HTML portion, I'm not allowed to post it all, it exceeds the size limits:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <FORM method="post" action="/scripts/send_form_email.php" name="BecomeForm" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
            <table BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="520">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="520">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" align="right" width="100"><font color="#cc0000">First Name:</font></td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100">
                                <input type="text" SIZE="20" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" width="200" colspan="2"><font color="#cc0000">Last Name:</font></td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100">
                                <input type="text" SIZE="20" id="LastName" name="LastName" maxlength="30" value=""></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" align="right" width="100"><font color="#cc0000">eBay
                                  User ID:</font></td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100">
                                <input type="text" SIZE="20" id="UserID" name="UserID" maxlength="50" value=""></td>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" width="200" colspan="2">APS Number:</td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100">
                                <input type="text" SIZE="20" id="APSNumber" name="APSNumber" value=""></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" Width="100"><font color="#cc0000">Street Address:</font></td>
                                <td Colspan="4" ALIGN="left" Width="450">
                                <input SIZE="40" id="Address1" name="Address1" maxlength="80" value="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" Width="100">Room/Floor/Apt#:</td>
                                <td Colspan="4" ALIGN="left" Width="450">
                                    <input SIZE="40" id="Address2" name="Address2" maxlength="40" value="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" align="right" width="100"><font color="#cc0000">City:</font></td>
                                <td Colspan="4" ALIGN="left" width="180">
                                <input SIZE="40" id="City" name="City" maxlength="40" value=""></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" width="100"><font color="#cc0000">State/Province:</font></td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100">
                                <input id="State" name="State" maxlength="3" value="" size="20"></td>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" width="200" colspan="2"><font color="#cc0000">Postal&nbsp; Code:</font></td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100">
                                <input SIZE="10" id="PostalCode" name="PostalCode" value="" maxlength="12"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" width="100"><font color="#cc0000">Country:</font></td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100" colspan="4">
                                    <select id="Country" name="Country" size="1">
                                    <option value="004">Afghanistan</option>
                                    <option value="008">Albania</option>
                                    <option value="012">Algeria</option>
                                    <option value="016">American Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="020">Andorra</option>
                                    <option value="024">Angola</option>
                                    <option value="660">Anguilla</option>
                                    <option value="028">Antigua And Barbuda</option>
                                    <option value="032">Argentina</option>
                                    <option value="051">Armenia</option>
                                    <option value="533">Aruba</option>
                                    <option value="036">Australia</option>
                                    <option value="040">Austria</option>
                                    <option value="031">Azerbaijan</option>
                                    <option value="044">Bahamas</option>
                                    <option value="048">Bahrain</option>
                                    <option value="050">Bangladesh</option>
                                    <option value="052">Barbados</option>
                                    <option value="112">Belarus</option>
                                    <option value="056">Belgium</option>
                                    <option value="084">Belize</option>
                                    <option value="204">Benin</option>
                                    <option value="060">Bermuda</option>
                                    <option value="064">Bhutan</option>
                                    <option value="068">Bolivia</option>
                                    <option value="070">Bosnia and Herzegowina</option>
                                    <option value="072">Botswana</option>
                                    <option value="074">Bouvet Island</option>
                                    <option value="076">Brazil</option>
                                    <option value="086">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                                    <option value="096">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                                    <option value="100">Bulgaria</option>
                                    <option value="854">Burkina Faso</option>
                                    <option value="108">Burundi</option>
                                    <option value="116">Cambodia</option>
                                    <option value="120">Cameroon</option>
                                    <option value="124">Canada</option>
                                    <option value="132">Cape Verde</option>
                                    <option value="136">Cayman Islands</option>
                                    <option value="140">Central African Republic</option>
                                    <option value="148">Chad</option>
                                    <option value="152">Chile</option>
                                    <option value="156">China</option>
                                    <option value="162">Christmas Island</option>
                                    <option value="166">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                                    <option value="170">Colombia</option>
                                    <option value="174">Comoros</option>
                                    <option value="178">Congo</option>
                                    <option value="180">Congo, The Democratic Republic Of The</option>
                                    <option value="184">Cook Islands</option>
                                    <option value="188">Costa Rica</option>
                                    <option value="384">Cote D'ivoire</option>
                                    <option value="191">Croatia (Local Name: Hrvatska)</option>
                                    <option value="192">Cuba</option>
                                    <option value="196">Cyprus</option>
                                    <option value="203">Czech Republic</option>
                                    <option value="208">Denmark</option>
                                    <option value="262">Djibouti</option>
                                    <option value="212">Dominica</option>
                                    <option value="214">Dominican Republic</option>
                                    <option value="626">East Timor</option>
                                    <option value="218">Ecuador</option>
                                    <option value="818">Egypt</option>
                                    <option value="222">El Salvador</option>
                                    <option value="226">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="232">Eritrea</option>
                                    <option value="233">Estonia</option>
                                    <option value="231">Ethiopia</option>
                                    <option value="238">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                                    <option value="234">Faroe Islands</option>
                                    <option value="242">Fiji</option>
                                    <option value="246">Finland</option>
                                    <option value="250">France</option>
                                    <option value="254">French Guiana</option>
                                    <option value="258">French Polynesia</option>
                                    <option value="260">French Southern Territories</option>
                                    <option value="266">Gabon</option>
                                    <option value="270">Gambia</option>
                                    <option value="268">Georgia</option>
                                    <option value="276">Germany</option>
                                    <option value="288">Ghana</option>
                                    <option value="292">Gibraltar</option>
                                    <option value="300">Greece</option>
                                    <option value="304">Greenland</option>
                                    <option value="308">Grenada</option>
                                    <option value="312">Guadeloupe</option>
                                    <option value="316">Guam</option>
                                    <option value="320">Guatemala</option>
                                    <option value="324">Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="624">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                                    <option value="328">Guyana</option>
                                    <option value="332">Haiti</option>
                                    <option value="334">Heard and Mc Donald Islands</option>
                                    <option value="336">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                                    <option value="340">Honduras</option>
                                    <option value="344">Hong Kong</option>
                                    <option value="348">Hungary</option>
                                    <option value="352">Iceland</option>
                                    <option value="356">India</option>
                                    <option value="360">Indonesia</option>
                                    <option value="364">Iran</option>
                                    <option value="368">Iraq</option>
                                    <option value="372">Ireland</option>
                                    <option value="376">Israel</option>
                                    <option value="380">Italy</option>
                                    <option value="388">Jamaica</option>
                                    <option value="392">Japan</option>
                                    <option value="400">Jordan</option>
                                    <option value="398">Kazakhstan</option>
                                    <option value="404">Kenya</option>
                                    <option value="296">Kiribati</option>
                                    <option value="408">Korea, Democratic People's Republic Of</option>
                                    <option value="410">Korea, Republic Of</option>
                                    <option value="414">Kuwait</option>
                                    <option value="417">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                                    <option value="418">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
                                    <option value="428">Latvia</option>
                                    <option value="422">Lebanon</option>
                                    <option value="426">Lesotho</option>
                                    <option value="430">Liberia</option>
                                    <option value="434">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
                                    <option value="438">Liechtenstein</option>
                                    <option value="440">Lithuania</option>
                                    <option value="442">Luxembourg</option>
                                    <option value="446">Macau</option>
                                    <option value="807">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of</option>
                                    <option value="450">Madagascar</option>
                                    <option value="454">Malawi</option>
                                    <option value="458">Malaysia</option>
                                    <option value="462">Maldives</option>
                                    <option value="466">Mali</option>
                                    <option value="470">Malta</option>
                                    <option value="584">Marshall Islands</option>
                                    <option value="474">Martinique</option>
                                    <option value="478">Mauritania</option>
                                    <option value="480">Mauritius</option>
                                    <option value="175">Mayotte</option>
                                    <option value="484">Mexico</option>
                                    <option value="583">Micronesia, Federated States Of</option>
                                    <option value="498">Moldova, Republic Of</option>
                                    <option value="492">Monaco</option>
                                    <option value="496">Mongolia</option>
                                    <option value="500">Montserrat</option>
                                    <option value="504">Morocco</option>
                                    <option value="508">Mozambique</option>
                                    <option value="104">Myanmar</option>
                                    <option value="516">Namibia</option>
                                    <option value="520">Nauru</option>
                                    <option value="524">Nepal</option>
                                    <option value="528">Netherlands</option>
                                    <option value="530">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                                    <option value="540">New Caledonia</option>
                                    <option value="554">New Zealand</option>
                                    <option value="558">Nicaragua</option>
                                    <option value="562">Niger</option>
                                    <option value="566">Nigeria</option>
                                    <option value="570">Niue</option>
                                    <option value="574">Norfolk Island</option>
                                    <option value="580">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                                    <option value="578">Norway</option>
                                    <option value="512">Oman</option>
                                    <option value="586">Pakistan</option>
                                    <option value="585">Palau</option>
                                    <option value="275">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                                    <option value="591">Panama</option>
                                    <option value="598">Papua New Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="600">Paraguay</option>
                                    <option value="604">Peru</option>
                                    <option value="608">Philippines</option>
                                    <option value="612">Pitcairn</option>
                                    <option value="616">Poland</option>
                                    <option value="620">Portugal</option>
                                    <option value="630">Puerto Rico</option>
                                    <option value="634">Qatar</option>
                                    <option value="638">Reunion</option>
                                    <option value="642">Romania</option>
                                    <option value="643">Russian Federation</option>
                                    <option value="646">Rwanda</option>
                                    <option value="659">Saint Kitts And Nevis</option>
                                    <option value="662">Saint Lucia</option>
                                    <option value="670">Saint Vincent And The Grenadines</option>
                                    <option value="882">Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="674">San Marino</option>
                                    <option value="678">Sao Tome And Principe</option>
                                    <option value="682">Saudi Arabia</option>
                                    <option value="686">Senegal</option>
                                    <option value="690">Seychelles</option>
                                    <option value="694">Sierra Leone</option>
                                    <option value="702">Singapore</option>
                                    <option value="703">Slovakia (Slovak Republic)</option>
                                    <option value="705">Slovenia</option>
                                    <option value="090">Solomon Islands</option>
                                    <option value="706">Somalia</option>
                                    <option value="710">South Africa</option>
                                    <option value="239">South Georgia And The South Sandwich Islands</option>
                                    <option value="724">Spain</option>
                                    <option value="144">Sri Lanka</option>
                                    <option value="654">St. Helena</option>
                                    <option value="666">St. Pierre And Miquelon</option>
                                    <option value="736">Sudan</option>
                                    <option value="740">Suriname</option>
                                    <option value="744">Svalbard And Jan Mayen Islands</option>
                                    <option value="748">Swaziland</option>
                                    <option value="752">Sweden</option>
                                    <option value="756">Switzerland</option>
                                    <option value="760">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                                    <option value="158">Taiwan, Province Of China</option>
                                    <option value="762">Tajikistan</option>
                                    <option value="834">Tanzania, United Republic Of</option>
                                    <option value="764">Thailand</option>
                                    <option value="768">Togo</option>
                                    <option value="772">Tokelau</option>
                                    <option value="776">Tonga</option>
                                    <option value="780">Trinidad And Tobago</option>
                                    <option value="788">Tunisia</option>
                                    <option value="792">Turkey</option>
                                    <option value="795">Turkmenistan</option>
                                    <option value="796">Turks And Caicos Islands</option>
                                    <option value="798">Tuvalu</option>
                                    <option value="800">Uganda</option>
                                    <option value="804">Ukraine</option>
                                    <option value="784">United Arab Emirates</option>
                                    <option value="826">United Kingdom</option>
                                    <option value="840">United States</option>
                                    <option value="858">Uruguay</option>
                                    <option value="860">Uzbekistan</option>
                                    <option value="548">Vanuatu</option>
                                    <option value="862">Venezuela</option>
                                    <option value="704">Viet Nam</option>
                                    <option value="092">Virgin Islands (British)</option>
                                    <option value="850">Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option>
                                    <option value="876">Wallis And Futuna Islands</option>
                                    <option value="732">Western Sahara</option>
                                    <option value="887">Yemen</option>
                                    <option value="891">Yugoslavia</option>
                                    <option value="894">Zambia</option>
                                    <option value="716">Zimbabwe</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" align="right" width="100">Phone:</td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100"><input SIZE="20" id="Phone" name="Phone" maxlength="17" value=""></td>
                                <td class="info" align="right" width="200" colspan="2"><font color="#000000">Extension:</font></td>
                                <td ALIGN="left" width="100"><input SIZE="10" id="Extension" name="Extension" maxlength="10" value=""></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" Width="100"><font color="#cc0000">E-Mail Address:</font></td>
                                <td Colspan="4" ALIGN="left" Width="450">
                                <input SIZE="40" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" maxlength="40" value="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" Width="100">Other Stamp Club Affiliation:</td>
                                <td Colspan="4" ALIGN="left" Width="450">
                                <input SIZE="40" id="OtherClub" name="OtherClub" maxlength="40" value="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" Width="100">
                                <font color="#CC0000">Your Collecting Interests:</font></td>
                                <td Colspan="4" ALIGN="left" Width="450">
                                <textarea name="Interests" rows=5 cols=48 wrap=virtual></textarea>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="info" ALIGN="right" Width="100">
                                <font color="#CC0000">Are you an Existing eUSC Member?</font></td>
                                <td Colspan="2" ALIGN="left" Width="225">
                                <input type="radio" value="No" checked name="Member">No</td>
                                <td Colspan="2" ALIGN="left" Width="225">
                                <input type="radio" name="Member" value="Yes">Yes</td>
                            </tr>
                            <input type=hidden name="submiturl" value="www.iusc.org">
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="0" width="520">
                <tr>
                    <td ALIGN="right" Width="100"></td>
                    <td class="info"><font color="#cc0000"><i>* Captions in RED denote required fields.</i></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="0" width="520">
                <tr>
                    <td width="450" align="right">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
                        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset">
                        <p align="left">
                            <font size="2">Clicking 'Submit' should launch your email program 
                            with the appropriate info filled in already.&nbsp; Just select 
                            'Send' to send in your membership request.</font>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

And the PHP File complete, but not finished:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
echo $_POST["FirstName"];
echo $_POST['LastName'];
echo $_POST['UserID'];
echo $_POST['APSNumber'];
echo $_POST['Address1'];
echo $_POST['PostalCode'];
echo $_POST['EMailAddress'];
echo $_POST['Phone'];
echo $_POST['City'];
echo $_POST['State'];
echo $_POST['Country'];
echo $_POST['Extension'];
echo $_POST['OtherClub'];
echo $_POST['Interests'];
echo $_POST['Member'];

if(isset($_POST['EmailAddress'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com";
    $email_subject = "eUSC Membership Request";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['FirstName']) ||
        !isset($_POST['LastName']) ||
        !isset($_POST['UserID']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Address1']) ||
        !isset($_POST['PostalCode']) ||
        !isset($_POST['EmailAddress']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Phone'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a missing entry in the form you submitted.');      
    }


    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName']; // required
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName']; // required
    $UserID = $_POST['UserID']; // required
    $APSNumber = $_POST['APSNumber']; // required
    $Address1 = $_POST['Address1']; // required 
    $City = $_POST['City']; // required
    $State = $_POST['State']; // required
    $PostalCode = $_POST['PostalCode']; // required
    $Country = $_POST['Country']; // not required
    $EmailAddress_from = $_POST['EmailAddress']; // required 
    $Phone = $_POST['Phone']; // required
    $Extension = $_POST['Extension']; // not required
    $OtherClub = $_POST['OtherClub']; // not required
    $Interests = $_POST['Interests']; // not required 
    $Member = $_POST['Member']; // not required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$EmailAddress_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email UserID you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$FirstName)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$LastName)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($FirstName)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($LastName)."\n";
    $email_message .= "UserID: ".clean_string($UserID)."\n";
    $email_message .= "APSNumber: ".clean_string($APSNumber)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address1: ".clean_string($Address1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address2: ".clean_string($Address2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($City)."\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($State)."\n";
    $email_message .= "PostalCode: ".clean_string($PostalCode)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($Country)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($EmailAddress_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($Phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Extension: ".clean_string($Extension)."\n";
    $email_message .= "OtherClub: ".clean_string($OtherClub)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Interests: ".clean_string($Interests)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Member: ".clean_string($Member)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$EmailAddress_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$EmailAddress_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<p><a href="index.htm">Back to the Auction!</a></p>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: post the php code as well thanks

Comment: before your `echo $_POST[...]` try and add this. `print_r($_POST);` this will help you debug by spitting out the contents of the array.

Comment: Post your full code for everything, HTML form and PHP. As it stands, your question is unclear.

Comment: oi, dat html is 'urtin me eyes.

Comment: print_r($_POST) shows Array() only.

Comment: Here is the full HTML portion, all 568 lines of it: Too long by a bunch. :(

Answer (score 1):

> Yet when I peek into the URL with Firebug in Firefox, I see the variables (all 15) properly populated.

You are using the `$_POST` variable, however the above states that the variables are appended to the URL, this is of type `$_GET`

If you want to `POST` the variables, they will be sent in the header and not visible to the user in the URL. to do this, change your form method.

```
<form method="POST" ...
```

Otherwise, just change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: You stand at being right, but I never post answers for questions like these.

Comment: Ehh, I like to teach coding, and I see people make small mistakes all the time. I like helping people learn from their mistakes, even if they dont take the time to research it them-self. *sometimes*

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more.

Comment: Plus, when I see `<!--webbot b-allow-letters="TRUE"` that is MS Frontpage syntax ;) I'm thinking "method" for sure, and maybe even "action" related. Could be anything really.

Comment: Read the whole question over again and go over it very carefully. (wink) This is the type of question where the OP **must** post full code for everything. Pay special attention to the part where OP states: *"I believe I can ignore the webbot stuff, I'm actually handling the validation in the php script."* and *"I'm getting notices like this (15 of them, one for each variable passed from the form)"* - Question is today's Prize Winner for "unclear what is asking". This is a **big can of worms,** if I ever saw one. `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">` could also play a big role.

Comment: <FORM method="post" action="/scripts/send_form_email.php" name="BecomeForm" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
I'll try it with the leftover webbot stuff removed.

Comment: Still same results with the webbot lines removed.